# Using Eclipse Update Sites after SSL redirect

Tags: eclipse, ssl, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Recently I've set up the ClearCase Remote Client (an eclipse plugin) to work through SSL, so instead of an http URL, it follows an https URL.

However, this breaks the access to the Update Site, returning an error that the site has a "Premature End of File" error.

My question(s) are this...

Is there a problem with Eclipse accessing Update Sites that have been reached through a redirect rule?

or

Is there a problem accessing Eclipse Update Sites through a SSL connection?

Any tips or anecdotes would be awesome!

**EDIT** : The link works via the browser, in terms of a redirect, but not in Eclipse when I attempt to access the same directory via the Update Site tool.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using, btw ?

Comment: 3.3.2, but tried it in 3.4 and it is the same issue.

Comment: Ok. I will make some test tomorrow, and complete my answer if I find anything

Comment: As asked in my answer below: Just do be sure, you did Enable HTTP proxy connection ?

Comment: I just tried with an old CCRC client 3.2: it works (behind a proxy with authentication). Could you check your error log files and see if there are other details in it you could post ? Otherwise, wait 24h... and set a bounty ;)

Comment: Note: there are 2 places in a CCRC client for the proxy to be declared: General/Connection and General/ Installation-Updates. Did you set both ? Even encapsulated in an eclipse client, it may be worth to check for multiple proxy settings in the preferences...

Comment: What CCRC update remove address are you using ? http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/ccrc/701/update/site.xml or the old one http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/ccrc/70/update/site.xml ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm actually pointing at the standard update site that comes with the installation of CCRC - i.e. https://<servername>/ccrc/update

Comment: I really appreciate all your work on this, sure I could slip a bit of bounty your way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although VonC made a really valiant effort, my answer or workaround has been to configure RWP to use SSL for the CCRC Server, and simple Port 80 for the Update Site with a redirect for any users who are still pointing at the old URL.

I am still unsure why it doesn't work in Eclipse with SSL though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a [known issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg17592.html) for other plugins as well

What is the "description site" looks like in your eclipse p2 configuration ?  Does it include https as in:

```
<description url="https://<host_name>/<update_site>/">
  Project Update Site
</description>
```

---

Just do be sure, you did [Enable HTTP proxy connection](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg20874.html) ?

(`General->Network Connections`)

Comment: Which is a great shame, as it seems to be featuring the same errors. "Premature End of File" :S

Comment: Yep, I've enabled HTTP Proxy Connection and given it the local proxy within General->Network Connections, still no dice.